# How to combine data composition and monad transformers

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad

I'm somewhat new to monad transformers, and currently trying to use a `StateT/Except` stack in a project.  The difficulty I'm having is that I have a few layers of data composition (types with operations on them, contained within types that have other operations on them), and I can't figure out how to elegantly  use monad transformers in that design.  Concretely, I'm having trouble writing the following code (simplified example, obviously):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except (Except, throwE)
import Control.Monad.Trans.State (StateT)

data ComposedState = ComposedState { state :: Bool }
data MyError = MyError { message :: String }

-- If the passed in state is true, change it to false; otherwise throw.
throwingModification :: ComposedState -> Except MyError ComposedState
throwingModification (ComposedState True) = return $ ComposedState False
throwingModification _ = throwE $ MyError "error!"

-- A state which composes with @ComposedState@,
data MyState = MyState { composed :: ComposedState }

-- and a monad transformer state to allow me to modify it and propagate
-- errors.
newtype MyMonad a = MyMonad { contents :: StateT MyState (Except MyError) a }
  deriving ( Functor
           , Applicative
           , Monad
           , MonadState MyState
           , MonadError MyError )

anAction :: MyMonad ()
anAction = do -- want to apply throwingModification to the `composed` member,
              -- propogating any exception
              undefined
```

where I have a potentially "throwing" operation on `ComposedState`, and I want to use that operation in a stateful, throwing operation on `MyState`.  I can obviously do that by deconstructing the whole stack and rebuilding it, but the whole point of the monadic structure is that I shouldn't have to.  Is there a terse, idiomatic solution?

Apologies for the lengthy code snippet--I did my best to cut it down.

Comment: `gets composed >>= MyMonad . lift . throwingModification`

Comment: That doesn't typecheck...  I suppose that's the idea though

Comment: Ah, I see how to get from there to what I want.  I guess I still haven't incorporated MonadTrans itself into my toolbox for when I want to move around layers of the stack; I'll work on that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more natural way of doing this would be to write `throwingModification` from the start in the `MyMonad` monad, like so:

```
throwingModification' :: MyMonad ()
throwingModification' = do ComposedState flag <- gets composed
                           if not flag then throwError $ MyError "error!"
                             else modify (\s -> s { composed = (composed s)
                                                    { Main.state = False } })
```

I'm assuming here that the composed states contain other components that you want to preserve, which makes the `modify` clause ugly.  Using lenses can make this cleaner.

However, if you're stuck with the current form of `throwingModification`, you'll probably have to write your own combinator, since the usual State combinators don't include mechanisms for switching the state type `s`, which is what you're effectively trying to do.

The following definition of `usingState` may help.  It transforms a `StateT` operation from one state to another using a getter and setter.  (Again, a lens approach would be cleaner.)

```
usingState :: (Monad m) => (s -> t) -> (s -> t -> s) 
                           -> StateT t m a -> StateT s m a
usingState getter setter mt = do
  s <- get
  StateT . const $ do (a, t) <- runStateT mt (getter s)
                      return (a, setter s t)
```

I don't think there's an easy way to modify `usingState` to work between general `MonadState` monads instead of directly on a `StateT`, so you'll need to lift it manually and convert it through your `MyMonad` data type.

With `usingState` so defined, you can write the following.  (Note `>=>` comes from `Control.Monad`.)

```
MyMonad $ usingState getComposed putComposed $
             StateT (throwingModification >=> return . ((),))
```

with helpers:

```
getComposed = composed
putComposed s c = s { composed = c }
```

This is still a little ugly, but that's because the type `t -> Except e t` must be adapted to `StateT (t -> Except e ((), t))`, then transformed to the `s` state by the combinator, and then wrapped manually in your `MyMonad`, as explained above.

### With Lenses

I'm not suggesting lenses are a miracle cure or anything, but they do help clean up a few of the uglier parts of the code.

After adding lenses:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad ((>=>))
import Control.Monad.Except (Except, MonadError, throwError)
import Control.Monad.State (get, MonadState, runStateT, StateT(..))

data MyError = MyError { _message :: String }
data MyState = MyState { _composed :: ComposedState }
data ComposedState = ComposedState { _state :: Bool }

makeLenses ''ComposedState
makeLenses ''MyError
makeLenses ''MyState
```

the definition of `throwingModification` looks a little cleaner:

```
throwingModification :: ComposedState -> Except MyError ComposedState
throwingModification s =
  if s^.state then return $ s&state .~ False
  else throwError $ MyError "error!"
```

and the `MyMonad` version I gave above certainly benefits:

```
throwingModification' :: MyMonad ()
throwingModification' = do
  flag <- use (composed.state)
  if flag then composed.state .= False
    else throwError (MyError "error!")
```

The definition of `usingStateL` doesn't look much different:

```
usingStateL :: (Monad m) => Lens' s t -> StateT t m a -> StateT s m a
usingStateL tPart mt = do
  s <- get
  StateT . const $ do (a, t) <- runStateT mt (s^.tPart)
                      return (a, s&tPart .~ t)
```

but it allows the existing lens `composed` to be used in place of helper functions:

```
  MyMonad $ usingStateL composed $
        StateT (throwingModification >=> return . ((),))
```

and it would generalize to `(composed.underneath.state4)` if you had complex nested state.

Comment: Thanks! Your second solution is pretty much what I came up with.  Writing everything as a `MyMonad` from the beginning seems like poor design; I want to keep everything split up into a few components without circular dependencies.  I should learn how to use lenses--I've always done my best to stay away from template haskell, but maybe it's sometimes necessary.

Comment: I've already accepted the answer, but if you could elaborate on how lenses would ameliorate the problem I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I've taken a similar approach In the past (tailored, minimal monad stacks wrapped in custom data types for different application components) on the basis that it seemed like better design.  However, I've found it to be detrimental to the development process with no real tangible benefits.  At least for one-programmer projects, I now think it's better to define a single `type M a = ...` monad and get everything running.  The type checker makes it easy to go back and refactor the monads, if you really find it's necessary (and it typically isn't).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be re-write `throwingModification` as a `MyMonad`.

```
throwingModification :: MyMonad ()
throwingModification = do
    s <- get
    if state s then
        put $ ComposedState False
    else
        throwError $ MyError "error!"
```

If you can't re-write your function (because it is used elsewhere), you can wrap it instead.